# Injecting a service into a factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, dependency-injection, factory

I am trying to inject a service into a factory but the tests are throwing two different types of error depending on if I inject the service into the constructer or import as private static variable.

**Injecting inside constructor**

```js
  import {MyService} from "../path";
  
  export class MyFactory() {
    constructor(private mySrv: MyService) {
      // usage example: this.mySrv.mySrvMethods(..blabla..)
    }
}
```

This is not getting really injected as in my `index.ts`file, the service is not there when I run the app.

**Injecting as an instance property of the factory class**

```js
import {MyService} from "../path";

class MyFactory() {

  private mySrv: MyService;
  constructor() {}
  // Usage: MyFactory.mySrv.mySrvMethods()
}
```

This also throws `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating MyFactory.mySrv.mySrvMethod)` in ....

The way I inject these in my tests are:

```js
describe('MyFactory', function() {
  var myService, myFactory, others;
  beforeEach(inject(function(myFactory, myService, others) {
    myFactory = myFactory;
    myService = myService;
  })
);
describe('my factory method 1', function() {
 spyOn(myService, 'mySrvMethod1').and.returnValue('random test');
 // myService is not injected as it says undefined
});
```

Comment: Please include the code how you register your factory / services with angular.

Comment: Added a test case code

Comment: For any Angular dependency injection to work you need to register all factories / services with Angular - otherwise nothing will be injected.

Comment: Do you mean something like this before injecting:  `beforeEach(function () {
    myService = System.registry.get(System.normalizeSync('app/myservice.service')).MyService;
  });`

Comment: Ok - other question: Are you writing Angular Code since this is the tag of your question or what are you trying to do?

Comment: It's angular1 with typescript. Here, I just want to inject the service inside the factory so I can use the methods inside the service. It works fine without throwing any error inside the factory (means that the service is properly injected) but unfortunately throws error in tests (undefined error shown above).

Comment: In the `index.ts`file where every controller, directives, factories etc are registered, I see that the service is not injected inside the factory.

Comment: Make sure to initialize your module in your tests: `beforeEach(module('app'));` - see https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/unit-testing. Are you doing this?

Comment: Yes, I'm doing that. The test runs perfectly if I don't inject the service. When, I inject the service, it doesn't recognize it in tests. I suppose, it has to do with service needing to be instantiated with new(). But, I'm not sure where i need to instantiate/mock the service call.

Comment: Ok, honestly it's impossible to get any further if you do not post the code where you register with angular as well as how you instantiate the module in your tests.